# ExecuteNonQuery inside of Reader

Tags: vb.net, executenonquery, oledbdatareader

How can I solve this problem? I do not want to use two connections.
ExecuteNonQuery only works if reader is closed.

```
oleCnn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
oleCnn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
oleCmm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
oleCnn.Open()
oleStr = "SELECT ID_Process FROM MyProcessTable"
Dim reader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = oleCmm.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            For i = 1 To NumExecutions
                    oleStr = "INSERT INTO MyOtherProcessTable(reader.getInt32(0))"           
                    oleCmm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
        End While
reader.Close()
oleCnn.Close()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list to store your IDs while reading the `DataReader`, then for each element of the list you should be able to execute your query with then same connection:

```
oleCnn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
oleCnn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
oleCmm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
oleCnn.Open()
oleStr = "SELECT ID_Process FROM MyProcessTable"

Dim ids As New List(Of Integer)

Dim reader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = oleCmm.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
    ids.Add(reader.GetInt32(0))
    End While
reader.Close()

For Each curr_id As Integer In ids
    For i = 1 To NumExecutions
        oleStr = "INSERT INTO MyOtherProcessTable(" & curr_id.ToString & ")"
        oleCmm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
Next
oleCnn.Close()
```

P.S. I don't understand the `For i = 1 To NumExecutions` for loop, but I added it as you wrote it