# Visual Basic 2010 and Mysql Nested Query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm using VB2010 Express, I've got a Mysql tablet with the following Fields Ext, CostAssing and CostAct, I'm trying to update a Mysql table from the result got in a first query:

- First query Get Ext and CostAssing
- Second Query Update field CostAct with CostAssing value

**

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Public dbconn As New MySqlConnection
    Public sql As String
    Public sqlQuery As String
    Public SQLcmd As MySqlCommand
    Public dbcomm As MySqlCommand
    Public dbread As MySqlDataReader
    Dim Ext As String
    Dim CostAssing As Integer
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        dbconn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost ; user id=root ; password=password ; database=calls")
        'First Query Get Extension and CostAssing
          Try
            dbconn.Open()
            sqlQuery = "SELECT Ext,CostAssing FROM estruc "
            SQLcmd = New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, dbconn)
            dbread = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader
            While dbread.Read()
                Ext = dbread.Item("Ext")
                CostAssing = dbread.Item("CostAssing")
                MsgBox("Ext:" & Ext)
                'Second Query Update Ext from CostAct to CostAssing
                Try
                    sqlQuery = "UPDATE estruc SET CostAct = '" & "1000" & "'  WHERE Ext = '" & Ext & "'"
                    SQLcmd = New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, dbconn)
                    dbread = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("Error 2 is :" & ex.Message)
                End Try
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error 1 is :" & ex.Message)
        End Try
        dbread.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**

The first query run ok, I get fields Ext and CostAssing, But When the second Query try to Update de field CostAct I get following error (Reported by Catch ex As Exception MsgBox("Error 2 is :" & ex.Message)):

"Error 2 is: There is already an open Datareader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."

PLease, Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to close the datareader after the first query

```
dbread.Close();
```

You'll want to store the values from dbread first (datatable or list, etc), close the while loop, then run the second query with:

```
SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Please see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303970/executenonquery-inside-of-reader)